# reference to removed assembly persists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, webforms, .net-assembly

I have a Visual Studio solution for a Web Forms application with few projects inside it. Some of the projects are built in dll form and used in the main project. Recently I completely removed from solution one of the dll projects and, for what is worth it, I created another one which uses an identical default namespace, generates a dll with same name, has identical or very similar functionality and type names. The initial project was using a third party module in form of dll identified with version, say, 1.2.3.4. The replacement project does not use that module. Now when I build the solution I get several errors like:

The type 'SomeType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ThirdParty, Version=1.2.3.4, etc.

I searched the whole solution for that 1.2.3.4 information without founding it. I have analyzed solution and project files. I have cleaned the whole solution, I deleted everything in folders bin and obj. I checked the Web.config file. It also does not seem that it was a NuGet package. Of course, I also restarted Visual Studio. Everything several times.

How come that the builder still expects to find that assembly?

Why I don't get an error like  "type or namespace could not be found" or "the name does not exist"?

Where is that information stored?

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  The references are in the intermediate obj files.  They also can be in the csproj files.  Open csproj with notepad and see if you can find the references to the dlls.